# Gradle can't find transitive dependency for module dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project with two Android Gradle modules: a library, `:mylib`, and an app, `:demo`.  In the `build.gradle` for `:demo`, I added a dependency on `:mylib`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':mylib')
}
```

In turn, `:mylib` has this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.5.0'
}
```

The repo is set up correctly, and `:mylib` built fine before I added the `:demo` module to the project.  But now when I build, I get this:

```
Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':demo'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':demo:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.5.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android/3.5.0/ksoap2-android-3.5.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android/3.5.0/ksoap2-android-3.5.0.jar
         file:/home/kevin/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android/3.5.0/ksoap2-android-3.5.0.pom
         file:/home/kevin/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android/3.5.0/ksoap2-android-3.5.0.jar
         file:/home/kevin/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android/3.5.0/ksoap2-android-3.5.0.pom
         file:/home/kevin/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android/3.5.0/ksoap2-android-3.5.0.jar
     Required by:
         MyProject:demo:unspecified > MyProject:mylib:unspecified
```

I don't understand why `:demo` is even aware that `:mylib` uses ksoap2, let alone why it tries to resolve the dependency itself.  I don't think there's anything `public` or even `protected` in `:mylib` that exposes its use of ksoap2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are **including a module**, gradle is trying to resolve all **nested dependencies** (somenthing similar to a pom file).

The library `com.google.code.ksoap2-android` isn't in the jcenter or maven central repository and it is the reason of your issue.

Just add the repository where gradle can find this library.

Comment: So there's no way for my module to not expose dependencies that it resolves itself?

Comment: The same happens publishing the library in a maven repo. The library will not contain the nested depedencies which will be included in the pom file. The main project also in this case will resolve the nested dependencies.

Comment: Ah.  I was conceptualizing a module dependency like a project dependency in an Eclipse workspace.  I expected it to be treated like an uber-jar.